# Cannot bind ObservableCollection to List dp from xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a userControl named Switch which has a DependancyProperty of type List, named ImageList.
In my ViewModel, I create a ObservableCollection named imgList.
In My XAML window, I write the following line:

```
<loc:switch ImageList={Binding imgList}/>
```

To my greatest regret, this does not work at all and ImageList does not recieve the requested values.

ImageList is defined as the following:

```
public static readonly DependancyProperty ImageListProperty = DependancyProperty.Register
  ("ImageList", typeof(List<ImageSource>), typeof(Switch));

public List<ImageSource> ImageList {
  get { return (List<ImageSource>)GetValue(ImageListProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ImageListProperty, value); }
}
```

The viewModel is correct, as the following works:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding imgList}/>
```

It is interesting to note that this works correctly:

```
<loc:switch>
  <loc:switch.ImageList>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla.png"/>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla2.png"/>
  </loc:switch.ImageList>
</loc:switch>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show the binding in your usercontrol and your dependency property code

Comment: @DHN: Why is this of any significance? The important point is that ImageList stays the same and doesn't get the collection defined in the VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect an incoming value of `ObservableCollection<>` type (imgList) would match with `List<>` type (Switch.ImageList)?

Please make your types compatible.

One way is to redeclare `ImageListProperty` to `IList<>` type as `ObservableCollection<>` implements `IList` interface.

In WPF Binding would wouk when the target property's type is same or a base type to the source value. `ObservableCollection` doesnt derive from `List<>`.

**EDIT**

Your last example stops working because `IList<>` isnt instantiated implicitly (being an Interface) without explicit collection type supplied to it via XAML. Change `ImageListProperty` to `IList` (Not `IList<T>`).

You should it change this way....

```
 <loc:switch xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib">
   <loc:switch.ImageList>
     <coll:ArrayList>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla.png"/>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla2.png"/>
     </coll:ArrayList>
   </loc:switch.ImageList>
 </loc:switch>
```

This works because `ArrayList` is a concrete XAML serialized collection that implements `IList`. And `ObservableCollection<>` also does plain `IList`.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. The problem is, that the example that I brought before stops working:
      <loc:switch.ImageList>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla.png"/>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla2.png"/>
      </loc:switch.ImageList>
The error I recieve is that IList can only get one child

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my savior!

Comment: I have a follow-up question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007491/cannot-bind-dependencyproperty-of-type-ilist-from-both-xaml-and-setter
Can you please look it up? Thanks!