# Cannot bind DependencyProperty of type IList from both XAML and Setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

After implementing the propsed code from here:

[Cannot bind ObservableCollection to List dp from xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958476/cannot-bind-observablecollection-to-list-dp-from-xaml/16958848#16958848)

I found out that if I had several instances of the control in the same page, the IList recieved all the values given to all the controls.
I read online that in order to solve this, one must write:

```
SetValue(...) in the constructor.
```

This causes the Setter that is shown in above link not to work.
(I guess that is because this time we need the IList to be static and not per-instance).

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `SetValue(ImageListProperty , new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>());` in your constructor? And what do you mean by the 'Setter not work'?

Comment: Hi Maya I didnt get this....  **found out that if I had several instances of the control in the same page, the IList recieved all the values given to all the controls**

Comment: @Colin yes its help if i set the image source from the control defintion in the xaml and then i actually get "new" list for each image control but if i try to set the images source once from a style setter this is not work becuase the image source is empty after the SetValue(ImageListProperty, new...)

Comment: @WPF-it i ment that if i have 2 image controls in my xaml so both get the last sources becaouse the source list is and if i do SetValue(ImageListProperty , new...); the problem is solved because i get fresh sourve for each instance BUT then i cant set the source from a style setter because the source get empty in the ctor (because the SetValue function) and then the source stay empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetCurrentValue instead of SetValue.